# Middleman - Active class on subdirectory and children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleman

I'm new to Middleman and for the life of me I can't seem to dynamically set an active class to my navigation on a subdirectory *and* its children.

I have the following helper set, and it works for the subdirectory (example: /about/) however it doesn't apply it to the children (example: /about/otherpage.html)

```
module CustomHelpers
  def nav_link_to(link, url, opts={})
    if request.path == link
      prefix = '<li class="active">'
    else
      prefix = '<li>'
    end
    prefix + link_to(link, url, opts) + "</li>"
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved!

After rooting around the middleman blogs I discovered a genius solution from the [EmberJS](https://github.com/emberjs/website/blob/master/config.rb) site kindly published publicly on GitHub.

To clarify, their helper is this:

```
def link_to_page name, url
    path = request.path
    current = path =~ Regexp.new('^' + url[1..-1] + '.*\.html')

    if path == 'index.html' and name == 'about'
      current = true
    end

    class_name = current ? ' class="active"' : ''

    "<li#{class_name}><a href=\"#{url}\">#{name}</a></li>"
  end
```

And then set up your template in a ul tag:

```
<%= link_to_page 'Projects', '/projects' %>
```

This works for sub-directories and their children too.

Hope that helps!

Comment: What is the `name == 'about'` for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an even shorter version:

in config.rb:

```
helpers do
  def active_navigation(page)
    current_page.url.include?(page) ? "active" : ''
  end
end
```

and in your template, just define the path you'd like to check for:

```
<ul>
  <li class="<%= active_navigation("/projects") %>">
   <%= link_to_page 'Projects', '/projects' %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, on any page where URL path contains "/projects", the li will have an "active" class applied.

So, /projects, /projects/project1, /projects/list, etc., will all cause an active class to be applied.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that if you have a link to the home page (`<%= link_to_page 'Home', '/' %>`) this will also trigger?